# List of my favorite questions across all Stack Exchange sites

Tags: support, stack-exchange, bookmarks

Is there any way to list my favorite questions across all Stack Exchange sites? I want to know if it's possible to see them all in one page.

Comment: [Heihachi?](http://www.triadtoys.com/images/multiple_images/hei2.jpg)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can see all your favourites on all sites on your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/26642/meysam?tab=favorites).

Comment: Oh!! Didn't notice that.